# If A is a countable set, how can I show that A has countably many finite subsets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, set-theory

Lets say that A is a countable set. How would I go about showing that A has countably many finite subsets?

I need to show that for every $n \in N$, the set $P^n(A)$ of finite subsets - with exactly $n$ elements - of A is countable. How would I then show how the union $U_{n \in N} P^n(A)$ of all these sets is countable?

Comment: "The union of a countable number of countable sets is itself countable" should be a theorem you have access to.

Comment: Suppose $A=\mathbb{N}$. Let $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ be distinct primes. Consider the function $\phi : P^n(A)\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by $$\phi\Big(\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}\Big)=p_1^{a_1}\times \dots \times p_n^{a_n}$$ Show $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: @MatthewPilling With $a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_n$?

Comment: @Brian Moehring Yes. You beat me to it. $\phi$ wouldn't be a function otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

By the definition of a countable set, there exists an injection $f: A \to \Bbb{N}$.

Let $\mathcal{G}$ denote the set of all finite subsets of $A$.

Define $\xi: \mathcal{G} \to \Bbb{N}$  by
$\xi(G) = \prod_{k \mathop \in f(G)} p_{k + 1}$

where $p_n$ denotes the $n$th prime number.